# подскажите как поетапно реализовать на javascript

Tags: javascript

Вввожу в поле слово. нажимаю отправить. слово добавляться не перезагружая страници следующим.

Я не прошу за меня решать. а словами обяснить!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Словник</title>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:20%">
    <caption>Словник</caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">
        <form name="test" method="post" action="">
          <p>
            <b>Слово:</b><br>
            <input type="text" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
            <input type="reset" value="Очистить">
          </p>
        </form>
        </form>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1.</td>
      <td>function</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2.</td>
      <td>step</td>
    </tr>
    <td align="center">3.</td>
    <td>caption</td>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4.</td>
      <td>border</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">5.</td>
      <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">6.</td>
      <td>autofocus</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">7.</td>
      <td>defines</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">8.</td>
      <td>form</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```